# file handling with .rose (file extension ) cpp

Tags: c++, schema, filestream, file-handling

how to get the data from the rational rose (file extension->**".rose"**) files which are having schema related to some building( which data stored using .ifc files)using cpp file handling?
which data type should we use to store the data of .rose files?
**it is one of the api format**

Comment: We have no idea from from the details in your question what a ".rose" file is.

Comment: To just *read* the contents of the files, you need nothing more than what [the standard input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) already provides. How to *parse* the data in the file into different data *structures* depends on the format of the file, which few here probably knows about.

Comment: @RichardCritten it is one of the file extension which I am currently working, it is having schema of particular design which represents similar to json file(i.e arrays and lists). I started working just before 2 days and I don't how to parse the file ,to get complete data.(Is this information helpful )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that rose compiler can help. it has many libraries that can parse rose files and make AST(abstract syntax tree).